# How to set a 'system level' environment variable?

Tags: python, linux, bash, export, subprocess

I'm trying to generate an encryption key for a file and then save it for use next time the script runs. I know that's not very secure, but it's just an interim solution for keeping a password out of a git repo.

`subprocess.call('export KEY="password"', shell=True)` returns `0` and does nothing.
Running `export KEY="password"` manually in my bash prompt works fine on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

`subprocess.call('export KEY="password"', shell=True)`

creates a shell, sets your `KEY` and exits: accomplishes nothing.

Environment variables do not propagate to parent process, only to child processes. When you set the variable in your bash prompt, it is effective for all the subprocesses (but not outside the bash prompt, for a quick parallel)

The only way to make it using python would be to set the password using a master python script (using `os.putenv("KEY","password")` or `os.environ["KEY"]="password"`) which calls sub-modules or processes.

Comment: I tried `os.environ` first, but like you said it only exists for subprocesses. My script completes, exits, and then is run again later, so I have to save it. Is my only option to write a text file?

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder what's wrong with your bash export solution now? writing to a file is unsafe as you said. Sounds more and more like XY problem to me.

Answer (score 2):

Using Python:

```
#SET:
os.environ["EnvVar"] = "1"

#GET:
print os.environ["EnvVar"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a thing you can do. Your subprocess call creates a subshell and sets the env var there, but doesn't affect the current process, let alone the calling shell.